# How to catch a @JsonFormat exception in spring and handle it gracefully to process the payload?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a spring app in which I am using the `@JsonFormat` annotation to deserialize a date format. But when I sent an array of elements my entire payload fails even if one of the entries have an invalid date.

Is there a way I can surpass this by gracefully handling this exception, by either replacing the failed date with a default value or ignoring that array entry.

jackson.version: `2.7.5`,
spring.version: `5.0.0.RELEASE`

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
private Date date;
```

Comment: Please add your implementation in the question..I mean how you're using annotation JsonFormat and in what format it is coming , hence you see the exception. Also as understood, you have a mandatory field which fails in de-serialization , thus we can't use JsonIgnore on additional or null values.

Comment: I believe the format I use doesn't matter much. In my scenario, whenever I sent the wrong format I want it handled. Anyway I will add @JsonFormat annotation used anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom [deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map) for your class where you set a default value in case something goes wrong. Something like:

```
public class MyJsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
            DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        String date = jsonParser.getText();
        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return new Date();
        }

    }

}
```

Then on your class you could do something like:

```
class MyClass {
    //...Fields

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MyJsonDateDeserializer.class)
    private Date date;

    //...Fields
}
```

You could also add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` over your class if you know that its value is not necessary always.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this, but do I have to add both `@JsonFormat` and `@JsonDeserialize`?

Comment: Yes you have to add both.

Comment: Tried it, looks good. Marking the answer as correct. One thing I noticed is that even if I remove `@JsonFormat` annotation, the control comes to `MyJsonDateDeserializer `

Comment: Yes. Because you added `@JsonDeserialize`, which basically says that before you convert the json string to an object always go through this class. Therefore, the flow goes to the `MyJsonDeserializer`

Comment: With the format hard-coded in the deserializer, why do we still need the `@JsonFormat` annotation?

Comment: @Polygon if I was using custom serialisation with `@JsonSerialize` also `@JsonFormat` wouldn't make sense, here only custom deserialisation is taking place.