# Supressing InvalidFormatException/Deserialisation Exception for LocalDate field annotated with JsonFormat

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, exception, deserialization

I have an entity Class having a LocalDate field validated using @JsonFormat annotation as below

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate fieldDate;
```

I am getting a Deserialisation/InvalidFormat Exception when passing the following dates as input 0000-00-00. Instead, I wanted to suppress the exception thrown and make the normal flow possible. Please suggest to me some methods for the same

Comment: What do you expect the value of `fieldDate` to be for invalid dates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch a @JsonFormat exception in spring and handle it gracefully to process the payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137143/how-to-catch-a-jsonformat-exception-in-spring-and-handle-it-gracefully-to-proce)

Comment: Thanks tgdavies for response.Currently if we pass values like 0000-00-00 at entity level it is throwing InvalidFormattException/DeserialisarionException discarding entity.My req uirement is to suppress the InvalidFormattException/DeserialisarionException and go with normal flow.Any  solutions  for the same

Comment: What do you want the value of `fieldDate` to be with a "normal flow"?

Comment: It is LocalDate field which is  non mandatory one of format yyyy-mm-dd. In current context i wanted to suppress the exception thrown for invalid cases like 0000-00-00 and null from my pojo and return as null.Is there any way of achieving it?

Comment: Thanks team for the input.This worked for me. I have used a CustomDeserializer where i catch the invalid scenarios and return null for the same